# Are there differences in notation for the d'Alembert operator?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, differentiation, notation

On Wikipedia the d'Alembert operator is defined as
$$\square = \partial ^\alpha \partial_\alpha = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2 $$
However, my professor uses the notation:
$$ \square = \partial _\alpha \partial^\alpha$$
with $\partial_\alpha = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$ and $\partial^\alpha = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}$ 
Is there a difference or are both notations equivalent

Comment: In Minkowski space, what's the difference?

Comment: Hi Alessio Popovic. Suggestion: Instead of asking which is better, try to ask into the difference in definitions.

Comment: More relevant is which metric you use: (-1,1,1,1) or (1,-1,-1,-1). This will add a sign to the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, both expressions are the same: Note that
$$\partial^\alpha = \eta^{\alpha\beta}\, \partial_{\beta}$$ and hence

$$\square = \partial_\alpha\partial^\alpha = \partial_\alpha \eta^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta = \partial^\beta \partial_\beta \quad .$$

We have used the Minkowski space metric $(+1,-1,-1,-1)$.

Comment: Why so complicated? $\partial_\alpha$ and $\partial^\alpha$ commute.

Comment: Interesting, my professor used the metric (+,-,-,-).  Should there be a - sign?

Comment: @AlessioPopov It is just a difference in convention. It should always be clear which  convention is used. For (-1,1,1,1) there should be a sign.

Comment: @my2cts This answer is the proof that $\partial_\alpha$ and $\partial^\alpha$ commute. And it has to be proven, because they don't commute if the metric isn't constant.

Answer (score 2):

If operators commute, namely if commutator :
$$ [ \hat {x},\hat {y}] = \hat x \hat y - \hat y \hat x = 0$$, then there's no difference in order of operators applied, as in this case, because we know [Clairaut's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Clairaut.27s_theorem) :
$$ {\frac {\partial }{\partial x_{i}}}\left({\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}}\right)\ =\ {\frac {\partial }{\partial x_{j}}}\left({\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}}\right) $$

So these two expressions :
$$ \square = \partial _\alpha \partial^\alpha = \partial ^\alpha \partial_\alpha $$
are equivalent.